# Triggering a Plugin on Creation of a Process/Entity

Tags: plugins, crm

I have a requirement like when the admin creates a business process flow, I need to get all the stages associated to the business process flow and push them to a custom entity for my future reference.

My plan was to write a plugin and trigger it whenever the admin creates a process. But not able to get an appropriate message for the same. On checking the SDK list could see a Create message for processsession. But I believe that will be triggered every time when a session for processes happens and it will be a performance hit.

Is there any message which I can use in this case? Any other way to achieve this?

Appreciate all your ideas and suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible to run a create plugin on the `workflow` entity.

One option I can think of would be to have an external job that periodically queries the `workflow` entity. It would then figure out the new Business Process Flows created for your entity and ones have been modified since the last run (maybe by comparing the `xaml` attribute of the `workflow`entity?).

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("workflow");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("workflowid", "name", "xaml");
query.Criteria.AddCondition("primaryentity", ConditionOperator.Equal, "new_yourentity");
query.Criteria.AddCondition("businessprocesstype", ConditionOperator.Equal, 0); // Business Flow

var results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);

// add compare logic and write to new entity here
```

Comment: Thanks Shane Carvalho for the suggestion.